# Debug rule project in Eclipse Rule Designer

Tags: designer, rules, odm

Unable to create debug configuration to debug the rule flow, in Eclipse Rule Designer. As, it doesn't show any project to browse with.

I need to debug the complete rule flow in order to understand.

Comment: I didn't mark it as urgent explicitly

Comment: [See the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54151855/revisions).